# Draw animated elements based on data stored on a local resource

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a file structured like this:

```
abc=25.0000000000
def=50.0000000000
ghi=75.0000000000
lmn=100.000000000
...
```

And I want something like this on my website:

[image: Representation of my ideal configuration]

The data in the file is being updated every 10 seconds. I'd like to see it being updated too on the website without refreshing the page manually.

How can I do this? Pure-HTML solutions fascinate me, but I'm open to everything.

Comment: `setInterval`, AJAX

Comment: an SVG animation with keyframes

Comment: If you are looking for charts, see this excellent article: [https://medium.com/@heyoka/scratch-made-svg-donut-pie-charts-in-html5-2c587e935d72](https://medium.com/@heyoka/scratch-made-svg-donut-pie-charts-in-html5-2c587e935d72)

Answer (score 0):

You need Javascript, either load the file at once, or if it's updated in real time, use ajax  calls to get the values every 10 seconds. Then use a div with a border and border-radius to do the circle, and use `clip-path: polygon(x1% y1%, x2% y2%, ...)` to hide everything in the div but the slice you want to show (the polygon would be something like this: (50% 0, 100% 0, x% y%, 50% 50%) where x y values go around the circle and you can use trigonometric functions to get them from an angle proportional to the value you have in your file.